# R data frame with 2 columns to wide format using spread() or pivot_wider() getting duplicate/not unique error/warning message

Tags: r, transpose, spread

This is obviously an entry level question but just seems to indicate I might be missing some fundamentals of how R handles data transposition on a basic level...

Note, I have been reading all other messages/replies but I am still confused over why I couldn't perform this very simple task below .

Could someone at least explain to me what's happening here, also how to use those options in the warning message? (fairly straightforward to do in normal circumstances with 3 columns or more so something is missing here..)

My intention is to first create a data set of 2 columns with 100 records and 10 levels per fn variable, then transpose it into a wide dataset with 10 columns.

```
fn <- seq(1,10) 
val <- rnorm(100,0,1)

datout <- data.frame(fn,val)


##no duplicate
> which(duplicated(datout))
integer(0)

##pivot_wider gave me a listing with warning message:

datwd <- datout %>% 
  mutate(fn=paste0("type",fn)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=fn, values_from=val)
```

##only getting a listing with warning message:

## A tibble: 1 x 10

type1      type2      type3      type4      type5      type6      type7      type8      type9      type10
                                             
1 <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]> <dbl [10]>
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

- Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
- Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates ari**se
- Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

```
##spread() won't work at all

> datout %>% 
+  spread("fn", "val")
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got there. Your error message says: `Values are not uniquely identified`. If you look at the examples for `pivot_wider`, you will see that you need a unique identifier column to help guide the values into their correct position.

```
datout %>%
  
  dplyr::mutate(
    # Create an ID col
    ID = rep(1:10,times = 10) %>% sort,
    fn=paste0("type",fn)) %>% 
  
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    # Use ID col here
    id_cols = ID,
    names_from=fn, values_from=val)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 11
      ID  type1   type2  type3  type4   type5  type6  type7   type8  type9 type10
   <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  0.805 -1.81   -0.235 -0.986  1.05   -2.11   0.951  1.24    0.401  0.517
 2     2 -1.33  -0.433   0.939  0.263  0.412   1.58   0.864  0.223   0.541  0.530
 3     3 -0.785  0.0519 -0.581  0.527  0.0339  0.440  0.980 -1.75   -0.346  2.49 
 4     4  0.279  0.261  -1.21  -0.232 -1.00   -0.455  1.22  -0.434   0.262 -2.36 
 5     5 -0.559  0.684  -1.56   0.747 -0.195  -3.22   0.383  0.735  -1.30   0.539
 6     6  0.618  0.544  -2.45   0.936  0.0550  1.49   1.83  -1.19    0.257  0.875
 7     7  0.308 -1.94   -0.440 -0.855 -0.712   0.475  0.418  0.718   1.60  -1.44 
 8     8  0.877  1.60    1.34   1.90   0.381  -0.440 -0.266 -0.0980  1.82   0.538
 9     9  1.38   0.199  -0.165 -1.09   0.350   0.966 -1.58  -0.888   0.551  0.493
10    10  0.143 -0.476   0.118 -1.16  -1.57   -1.73   0.479 -0.401  -0.932 -0.469
```

Comment: Okay, so basically I had to retain another column artificially in order for the code to work...it's more of a record # here. I guess one thing to note is that all those type categories need to have the same number of records for this type of transpose to work reasonably, so maybe there is some sense underneath this practice. Thanks.

Comment: And this is a complaint to stackoverflow, part of my question was not answered, nor in any responses to other "similar" questions: also how to use those options in the warning message ...

Comment: You're right. You do need to have the same number of records per category.